# 3D reconstruction of an image based on depth of intensity levels?

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, image-segmentation

Is there anyway of segmenting objects based on how far they are from the viewer?

Can color values assess this sort of a thing for us?
How will intensity levels help in determining how far the object is from the viewer?

[image]

Another image:

[image]

Comment: This is not segmentation, it's [3D reconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_reconstruction). Do you have other images that capture the scene from a different view or under different lighting conditions?

Comment: i have provided another image with a different angle

Comment: Now you can follow http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_reconstruction_from_multiple_images

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an extremely difficult task, one which is a very active line of research. I've managed to find a [semi-recent paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11263-007-0071-y) on the subject entitled "
3-D Depth Reconstruction from a Single Still Image". I won't go into the details, but here's a few things that this paper found that can be used.

1. Textures: If you see a given texture, they can help you figure out how far something is away. The wood texture here would be quite ideal for this.
2. Fixed object sizes: Identify common objects, see how large they are, and use them to help with depth analysis. The phone book, soda bottle, etc should work well with this.
3. Focus: If you know how the picture was take, focus can help you identify ranges.
4. Shadows- If you know where the light was coming from, shadows can help you identify how tall objects are, and thus how far they are away.

Comment: Thanks for that reference yup will look into that however what more methods could be considered while approaching this problem

Comment: Most 3D techniques are found in research papers could i found codes related to these topics?

Comment: @vini [Cornell](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~asaxena/learningdepth/) has a research page with depth estimation from a single image and shares code.

Comment: Yes i do have that code however which file to run is a problem in it

Answer (score -1):

See this code from matlab website: "Depth from gradient":

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45269-dfgbox